# SELECT from VIEW fast, but WHERE causes slowness

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have quite a complex view, which uses a hierarchy table structure, which uses a hierarchy data type, and returns a lost of locations. Location is the hierarchy table.

The view does a pivot, in a CTE, and then uses that with some extra joins, to produce a useful list of data to the developers.

Here is the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwLocations] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    WITH p AS 
    (
    SELECT ID,
            [1] AS Facility,
            [2] AS Community,
            [3] AS Unit,
            [4] AS Pod,
            [5] AS Cell,
            [6] AS Bed,
            [7] AS Zone,
            [8] AS Building,
            [9] AS Room 
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                p.ID, 
                l.[Name], 
                l.[Level] + CASE WHEN l.LocationTypeID IN(11,12,13) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END AS Level -- Note, 11,12 and 13 are Non-Accomodation types, so the level needs to move to the Non-Accomodation area
            FROM dbo.Location AS l
            INNER JOIN dbo.Location AS p
                ON p.[Path].IsDescendantOf(l.[Path]) = 1
        ) AS p
        PIVOT (
            MAX(Name)
            FOR [Level] IN (
                [1],
                [2],
                [3],
                [4],
                [5],
                [6],
                [7],
                [8],
                [9]
            )
        ) AS pvt
    )
    SELECT ISNULL(l.ID,-999) AS LocationID, -- Done to allow EF to use the view. A view needs something that looks like a KEY.
            l.ParentID AS ParentID,
            LocationTypeID,
            lt.Description AS LocationType,
            l.GeoLocation,
            l.Name,
            p.Facility,
            p.Community,
            p.Unit,
            p.Pod,
            p.Cell,
            p.Bed,
            p.Zone,
            p.Building,
            p.Room

        FROM dbo.Location l
        INNER JOIN p
            ON p.ID = l.id
        INNER JOIN ref.LocationType lt
            ON lt.ID = l.LocationTypeID
GO
```

SELECT * FROM vwLocations runs in around 60ms. I'm pleased with that. When I join my view to some tables to produce a result set, this query is fast too:

```
SELECT 
    Per.Firstname, 
    per.Surname, 
    v.* 
FROM person per
INNER JOIN dbo.Prisoner pri
    ON pri.PersonID = per.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.vwLocations v
    ON v.LocationID = pri.CurrentAccommodationLocationID
```

This runs in less than half a second, returning 800 rows.

However, when I add a very basic WHERE clause to my query - the times blows out to between 4 and 6 seconds.

```
    SELECT 
        Per.Firstname, 
        per.Surname, 
        v.* 
    FROM person per
    INNER JOIN dbo.Prisoner pri
        ON pri.PersonID = per.ID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.vwLocations v
        ON v.LocationID = pri.CurrentAccommodationLocationID
    WHERE per.IsActive = 1
```

I'm baffled as to why a WHERE statement, on a different table than the VIEW, causes such a drastic loss of speed.

Here is the query execution plan for the query without the WHERE.
[image]

And here is the execution plan for the query WITH the WHERE clause.
[image]

Am I missing an index? Not, if I run the View by it's self, it's quick. And that returns all rows. So I am not sure the view is at fault - although, it's the only complex thing here.

:
[Execution plan WITH the where clause](https://www.dropbox.com/s/obo6fbmrp5o4yx4/PlanWithWhereClause.sqlplan?dl=0)

[Execution plan WITHOUT the where clause](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rncglc1a05fnwfa/PlanWithoutWhereClause.sqlplan?dl=0)

EDIT:

And here's something that is strange. If I filter on a different column in the Person table (At the moment, I filter on IsActive = 1), I get a quick response! So, when I run:

```
SELECT 
    Per.Firstname, 
    per.Surname, 
    v.*,
    *
FROM person per
INNER JOIN dbo.Prisoner pri
    ON pri.PersonID = per.ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.vwLocations v
    ON v.LocationID = pri.CurrentAccommodationLocationID
WHERE per.PersonTypeID = 7
```

This returns the same number of rows (Because I know that all Active people are PersonType 7). Only when I filter on IsActive (BIT NOT NULL), does it go slow.

Comment: pls add table schema definitions....

Comment: Can you move the `WHERE` filter to `JOIN` and post the results? Like this - `FROM person per
    INNER JOIN dbo.Prisoner pri
        ON pri.PersonID = per.ID
        AND per.IsActive = 1`

Comment: One possibility is that the stats are messed up and it thinks there are more/less active than there are so tried a different approach.  You can try this by adding `WHERE per.IsActive + 0 = 1` and seeing if it goes back to the good version.  If so, consider rebuilding stats.  Oh and if you have an index on IsActive get rid of it or make it conditional

Comment: could you post execution plan in xml

Comment: @Raj - I tried to move the WHERE to the INNER JOIN, but made no difference.

Comment: @LoztInSpace, I tried the  IsActive +0 = 1 - but again, no difference. I'm uploading the XML now.

Comment: Added execution plan XML.

Comment: http://jahaines.blogspot.hk/2010/03/performance-tuning-101-what-you-will_17.html See this.

Comment: Are you using a parameter to filter the per.IsActive (ie WHERE per.IsActive = @value ) or directly filter by 1 (WHERE per.IsActive = 1) ?

Comment: it would be great if you share schemas for all underlying tables.

Comment: hey @Craig
Sorry i am out of time today so just commentting i think this will slove your problem


create index IX on dbo.Location (Path)
 include (LocationTypeID, Name, Level)

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma - That seemed to help a bit! I'm going to play around with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a where clause to your query resulted in different plan and it is not accurate because,statistics are not accurate on location table.Statistics are key in getting a good plan.

Try updating statistics on objects involved in query and you will get a different plan..

[image]